# What's the meaning of rub it in your face?

Tags: meaning, idioms

p1 posted his bank account info and was excited to announce that he has paid off his mortgage. He is asking others to post their bank accounts as well.

p2 "I have more than that but I have enough tact not to rub it in your face."

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rub+it+in

Comment: Maybe a combination of [rub it in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rub+it+in) and [in your face](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/202800.html) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means to inform someone or remind someone that you are superior to him or more fortunate than him in a way that is excessive to the point of rudeness. That is, you are not just pointing out your advantage, but emphasizing it in a way calculated to embarass the other person or build yourself up.

Comment: Interesting. Is this idiomatic usage listed somewhere? What is the exact phrase? Can you try and post a link to that here?

Comment: @Kris Hmm, sorry, I don't know of any dictionary of idioms. But if you do a Google search on "rub it in your/his/my face", you'll find plenty of examples of this usage. (You also find a bunch where the phrase is used literally, like rubbing some kind of cream or make-up on your face. Obviously that's a totally different meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

It means to keep reminding somebody of what they have done wrong. The reference is to training a puppy by rubbing its nose in whatever it has deposited on the floor.

Comment: Isn't that more of an explanation for the idiom "rub your nose in it"? This isn't an example of someone doing something wrong. Rather they are gloating.

Comment: Nose or face, much the same thing. It can have a sense of gloating as in "you have done it wrong and I have done it well". I kind of understand what you are saying though. There is also "rub it in"in the sense of rubbing salt into a wound to make it hurt more, which seems to match better with the OP, but he specifically says "... rub it in your face"

Answer (score 0):

"Rub your face in it" does come from dog training but it has more do to with pointing out others mistakes and failures than it does flaunting one's own achievements.

I know this was a while back but I thought Jay really misled you on the meaning.  No offense intended.

Comment: We appreciate your input. We also appreciate links to sources where applicable, especially in *Answers*. You can help us learn by providing links, even with answers in response to seemingly opinion-based questions. Thanks. :)